# Remove duplicate lines in a text file

Tags: php, regex

I am in need to open a text file (file.txt) which contains data in the following format :-

```
dave : 50lb : hlof
jimmy : 55lb : okay
dave : 12lb : krsho
```

I want to remove lines that has duplicate start word So the result would look like this :-

```
dave : 50lb : hlof
jimmy : 55lb : okay
```

I've been thinking about using `array_unique` but didn't worked so any idea how it can be done .. maybe can be with `regex` !

Update

my try was

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode($lines));
```

but didn't worked cause it only compare the whole line if not the same will then consider it different

Comment: *but didn't worked* Why did it not worked? Show us your attempt! BTW: You have 3 different lines which you show us here

Comment: @Rizier123 i've updated the question with my try using `array_unique` ...

Comment: And you know that every file line which you show us here is unique?! Are you trying to compare only the first column (name) ?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes but i wonder if i can consider line that has same start word just before `:` are duplicated and to be removed. so `dave : 50lb : hlof` and `dave : 12lb : krsho` have same start word `dave` .

Comment: Rizier123 yep, i wanna compare based only on first colum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I first go through each element of `$lines` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) then I [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) every value with `:` and return the first element. After this I use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) with the created array from before where I use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get the unique keys and get the intersect with the full array)

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $lines = array_intersect_key($lines, array_unique(array_map(function($v){
        return trim(explode(":", $v)[0]);
    }, $lines)));

    print_r($lines);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => dave : 50lb : hlof [1] => jimmy : 55lb : okay )
```

Comment: @hwnd Thanks :), But I still have the feeling that there most be an easier way, but I can't think about it.

Comment: This method was the shortest way.

Comment: OMG i thought it was impossible to do so .. you are so genius .. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rizier123 I just want to confirm it works perfect as you've said without any error on PHP 5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6 since they all support `functions.anonymous` that answer did not just fixed my problem but also pushed me to move on and upgrade PHP to most stable version .. thanks a lot.

Comment: @RehamFahmy cool! Glad I could help. If you want to to make it more backwards compatible you could use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). But I think we live in 2015 and php 5.3 or 5.4 should be standard

Answer (score 0):

What errors or problems do you have with array_unique as it works for me:

```
$lines = file('foobar.txt');
$lines = array_unique($lines);
```

Update: Added before question was expanded

Comment: *Update: Added before question was expanded* You can still edit your answer to match the question

Comment: It was awesome of you to try to help ~ Thanks